# Error al iniciar y desinstalar Oracle 10g express

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle

Buenas noches tengo este problema al iniciar Oracle 10g.

Al darle iniciar me sale este mensaje:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando quiero desinstalarlo me aparece la ventana, carga por unos segundos y se cierra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué es lo que podría hacer? Intenté hacer lo que decían en varios foros y nada. El problema sigue. Agradecería si pudieran ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Este error se despliega normalmente cuando el codigo de instalacion necesita permisos de administrador.

Puedes intentar de dos maneras:

1. Clic derecho sobre el icono y ejecutar como administrador
2. Ejecutar el StarDB.bat desde un commmand prompt